# Using iPad as an external monitor

Tags: ipad

Is there a way to use the Apple iPad as an external monitor for Ubuntu? I see that there are applications for that purpose for Macintosh computers.

Comment: Oooohhh, good question, and one I'd be curious to know the answer to.

Comment: maybe VNC Viewer?

Comment: That would be a pretty neat idea but apple will stay apple while Ubuntu would gladly welcome it Apple would say "No". In other words Apple does not like to give neat features to non apple products. But best of luck to any wine possibilities even though I have trouble with it as far as number of compatible programs.

Comment: A note support waltinator's motion: Android or iPhone doesn't matter (that part is off topic here anyway); what matters is that you can use VNC for that task if you can find a VNC client for the target platform.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question is specific to iPads. It's easy on Android tablets as there are many VNC clients available on playstore. This question does not even say anything about VNC. So, if there is any better way, that would be highly appreciated .
I'll start a bounty if this question re-opens.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy guide, using VNC: http://eric-blue.com/2011/08/20/how-to-turn-your-ipad-into-a-virtual-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using one of the applications listed [on this article](http://geeknizer.com/use-ipad-as-second-monitor/):

- [Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display) (OSX)
- [MaxiVista](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/maxivista/id380146095?mt=8) (Windows)

You could try running it in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu), I went and did some advance searching and it seems the platforms are usually for Windows or Macintosh.

Comment: These are OS-X- or Windows-only applications and therefore off topic here. Not even Wine will help here, because that type of function requires the installation of a display driver and Wine doesn't do device driver installations.

Comment: Air Display has been broken for the last two years (since 2021) re comments in the Apple Store. Looks like abandonware.